# Line breaks in xtable cells

Tags: r, latex, newline, xtable

I'm using `xtable` to automatically generate LaTeX tables and would like to force a line-feed/break within cells.

This can be done using `\newline` within a cell, however I'm having trouble preventing `xtable` from substituting my backslashes (`\`) with `$\backslash$`.

Heres an example....

```
library(magrittr)
library(xtable)
my.data <- cbind(c("1", "2", "3"),
                 c("0", "1", "2"),
                 c("2", "3", "4")) %>%
           as.data.frame()
## Generate output variable
my.data$out <- paste0(my.data$V1,
                      " \\newline (",
                      my.data$V2,
                      " to ",
                      my.data$V3,
                      ")")
## Check the data frame...
my.data
  V1 V2 V3                  out
1  1  2  3 1 \\newline (2 to 3)
2  0  1  2 0 \\newline (1 to 2)
3  2  3  4 2 \\newline (3 to 4)
## Now generate xtable
xtable(my.data)
% latex table generated in R 3.2.0 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Wed Jun 24 11:51:59 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
  & V1 & V2 & V3 & out \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 $\backslash$newline (2 to 3) \\ 
2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 $\backslash$newline (1 to 2) \\ 
3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 2 $\backslash$newline (3 to 4) \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

The `paste0()` works fine as expected, but passing this data frame to `xtable` does not result in what I expected(/hoped for) which is....

```
xtable(my.data)
% latex table generated in R 3.2.0 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Wed Jun 24 11:51:59 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
  & V1 & V2 & V3 & out \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 \newline (2 to 3) \\ 
2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 \newline (1 to 2) \\ 
3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 2 \newline (3 to 4) \\ 
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

So that when parsed through LaTeX I get line breaks in that cell.

A similar question about [line breaks in captions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19937904/how-do-i-insert-a-line-break-in-an-xtable-caption) suggests using double-escaped backslashes but that doesn't work in this instance either...

```
my.data$out <- paste0(my.data$V1,
                      " \\\\newline (",
                      my.data$V2,
                      " to ",
                      my.data$V3,
                      ")")
% latex table generated in R 3.2.0 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Wed Jun 24 11:57:04 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & V1 & V2 & V3 & out \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 $\backslash$$\backslash$newline (2 to 3) \\ 
  2 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 0 $\backslash$$\backslash$newline (1 to 2) \\ 
  3 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 2 $\backslash$$\backslash$newline (3 to 4) \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Next I looked at the `xtable` [help](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/xtable.pdf) and [graph gallery](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xtable/vignettes/xtableGallery.pdf) and thought I might be able to use the `sanitise.text.function` to specify explicitly to substitute `\` with `\` (and I could then just use `\newline` within my `paste0()` call) but unfortunately this doesn't work either as the second `\` is treated as escaping the following closing double quote...

```
xtable(my.data, sanitise.text.function = function(str)gsub("\", "\",str,fixed=TRUE))
Error: unexpected input in:
"xtable(my.data,
       sanitise.text.function = function(str)gsub("\", "\"
```

Could I use the whole string `\newline` and substitute it with itself?

```
my.data$out <- paste0(my.data$V1,
                      " \newline (",
                      my.data$V2,
                      " to ",
                      my.data$V3,
                      ")")
xtable(my.data, sanitise.text.function = function(str)gsub("\newline", "\newline",str,fixed=TRUE))
% latex table generated in R 3.2.0 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Wed Jun 24 12:05:25 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & V1 & V2 & V3 & out \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 
ewline (0 to 2) \\ 
2 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 2 
ewline (1 to 3) \\ 
3 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 3 
ewline (2 to 4) \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

No joy since the `\n` is now treated as a linebreak when parsed through `xtable`.

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8732712/handling-latex-backslashes-in-xtable) suggested using `identity` as the function argument to `sanitise.text.function` but that didn't work either (nor does using an identity function of `function(x){x}`).  I found a [post on R-help](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/xtable-with-conditional-formatting-using-textcolor-td3566562.html) asking similar (but the problem was with `\t` being interpreted as a tab) but that didn't work either (again output omitted for brevity).

```
 my.data
  V1 V2 V3                  out
1  1  0  2 1 \\newline (0 to 2)
2  2  1  3 2 \\newline (1 to 3)
3  3  2  4 3 \\newline (2 to 4)
xtable(my.data, sanitise.text.function = identity)
% latex table generated in R 3.2.0 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Wed Jun 24 13:09:47 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & V1 & V2 & V3 & out \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 $\backslash$newline (0 to 2) \\ 
2 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 2 $\backslash$newline (1 to 3) \\ 
3 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 3 $\backslash$newline (2 to 4) \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

my.data
  V1 V2 V3                 out
1  1  0  2 1 \newline (0 to 2)
2  2  1  3 2 \newline (1 to 3)
3  3  2  4 3 \newline (2 to 4)
xtable(my.data,
       sanitise.text.function = identity)
% latex table generated in R 3.2.0 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Wed Jun 24 13:28:28 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rllll}
  \hline
 & V1 & V2 & V3 & out \\ 
  \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 
ewline (0 to 2) \\ 
  2 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 2 
ewline (1 to 3) \\ 
  3 & 3 & 2 & 4 & 3 
ewline (2 to 4) \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

It feels like I'm close with using `sanitise.text.function` option but I can't work it out.  Is there a way of doing this somehow?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions/insights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you configure `sanitize.*.function` using `options()` rather than `print()`?  For example,

```
options(xtable.sanitize.text.function=identity)
```

prevents conversion of `\` with `$\backslash$` in cells.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'm in the last week of finishing this work for a deadline and am too busy to check but will give this ago once the works done and I'm tidying things up.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that xtable.sanitize.text.function works. I used it as below

```
options(xtable.sanitize.text.function = line_break_function)

line_break_function <- function(x){
gsub("$<$br$>$","<br>",x)
}
```

I used it as below to add line breaks to text blocks in a summarise function

```
cv %>%
group_by() %>%
summarise(colname = paste(`summary`,":",`Submit Date`,collapse = ",<br>"))

print(xtable, type = "html")
```